# Passing Values among Winforms in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to obtain a value back to the parent form and below is the code that I was using for this and it was working fine until started loading the child-form in a panel control to avoid popup windows.

Code in the mainform which contains the Panel

```
MainMovement child = new MainMovement(new_dat, required_time, number);
child.TopLevel = false;
this.pnlmain.Controls.Add(child);
child.Show();
child.BringToFront();
///Obtaining value back from the child form
string updatingc = child.updatestatus; //This is not working, I am proceeding with some more functions depending on this value, but code does not work here after
```

Child form has a public value as updatestatus and it sets the value before closing the child form.

Please advise how to obtain this value. I believe it is something to do with changing `child.ShowDialog()` to `child.Show()`. (In order to load the form into a panel I had to change this, before that this was working fine).

Comment: Raise an event on child form close and pass the value of updatestatus in that event. Catch that event on main form and get the value. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977326/propagating-events-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.ShowDialog()` waits for a `DialogResult` before continuing, whereas `Show()` just shows the form and continues.  It is hard to say without knowing how your child form is working, but my guess is whatever updates or sets `updatestatus` in your child form doesn't update before your code reaches that line.

One possible solution involves a major refactoring of your code.  You can add an event to your MainMovement form that is triggered when `updatestatus` is changed.
*Note that I changed your `updatestatus` to `UpdateStatus` and turned it into a property*

```
public MainMovement : Form
{
    public event EventHandler Updated;
    private void OnUpdateStatus()
    {
        if (Updated != null)
        {
            Updated(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private String updatestatus;
    public String UpdateStatus
    {
        get { return updatestatus; }
        private set 
        {
            updatestatus = value;
            OnUpdateStatus();
        }
    }

    // rest of your child form code 
}

public ParentForm : Form
{
    public void MethodInYourExample()
    {
        // other code?
        MainMovement child = new MainMovement(new_dat, required_time, number);
        child.Updated += ChildUpdated;
        child.TopLevel = false;
        this.pnlmain.Controls.Add(child);
        child.Show();
        child.BringToFront();
    }

    void ChildUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var child = sender as MainMovement;
        string updatingc = child.UpdateStatus;
        //rest of your code
    }

}
```

Comment: HI, thank you. But I am getting the follwong error Error 7 Cannot assign to 'Update' because it is a 'method group'

Comment: @user2176442 doesn't tell me much but you are obviously trying to assign something to `Update`.  What is the line of code that is causing a problem?

Comment: Sorry, this is the code where i get the error "child.Update += ChildUpdated;"

Comment: opps, my bad... should be `child.Updated += ChildUpdated;`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: HI, thanx, I tried that, but in ChildUpdated in "//rest of you code", I just need to run a funcdtion again and the refresh a grid, which is not happening. Nothing changes same result. I just didi the same what you have advised.

Comment: How are you setting `UpdateStatus` in your child form?  Are you setting it through the property (`this.UpdateStatus = "some new value"`) or through the field (`this.updatestatus = "some new value"`)

Comment: Hi, when I used though the property it works, but I need to have a message box as when I receive the value to work the rest. After "string updatingc = child.UpdateStatus;" if not my grid is not getting refreshed. Any help on this?

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding your problem.  You need to show a `MessageBox` after `string updatingc = child.UpdateStatus;` based on the value of `updatingc`?  Can't you just call `MessageBox.Show()`?

Comment: No after receiving the value code is "this.Load_OpenD();             dataGridView1.Refresh();". dataGridView1 is on the parent form with in the same panel behind the child and if I do not have a message box before the above code, dataGridView1 will not get refreshed, but if a add a message box, data grid gets refreshed. Can I do this without a messagebox.

Comment: Maybe try calling `Refresh()` on your panel?  I'm not really sure as I'm not looking at your code in a debugger.  But it sounds like this might be a separate issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the object of your main form into child form via constructor. If you pass your object, you will have access to all the methods of parent form in your child. You can call any public method of main class to update your value.

```
MainMovement child = new MainMovement(this,new_dat, required_time, number);
child.TopLevel = false;
this.pnlmain.Controls.Add(child);
child.ShowDialog();
child.BringToFront();
```

Put one public method in your main form,

```
Public void UpdateValue(String pString)
{
      // Update your value
}
```

In your child form, you have to catch "this" with global object.

```
private oMainForm as MainForm

public void MainMovement(MainForm pObject,String new_dat, String required_time, Int number)
{
     oMainForm = pObject; 
     // Your Code
}
```

Now you can simply call your '**UpdateValue**' method from child form.

```
oMainForm.UpdateValue("Updated String");
```

Comment: hi, thanx, but ShowDialog() does not work when loading the form into a panel.

Comment: you can try the same method with show() also. Give it a try :-)

Comment: Hi, thanx, problem is sorted. Thank you again for your input. TC:)